# Push NuGet package: This package must be signed with a registered certificate

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to push my NuGet package with the commmand

```
dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key *** --skip-duplicate
```

But I'm receiving the error:

```
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (This package must be signed with a registered certificate.)
```

Is there any way to publish unsigned NuGet package? What are the requirements for unsigned packages?

I thought, it's not required to sign the package with a certificate. At least, I couldn't any information about this requirement in the official documentation.

What I remember, certificates for code signing are not free of charge, I would say they are quite expensive and it doesn't make sense for me to buy a certificate to publish one package once a year.

Comment: Does the account you're pushing the package to have any registered certificates?  The docs say once a certificate is registered, all packages pushed must now be signed with one of those certificates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/sign-a-package#register-the-certificate-on-nugetorg

Comment: @zivkan I've found in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/signed-packages-reference#signature-requirements-on-nugetorg:~:text=NuGet%20packages%20can%20include) that package can include a digital signature, so I suppose it's not required. I don't have any registered certificates.

Comment: that's right, it's not mandatory to sign packages, but the error message the server is giving you suggests that the account you're pushing to does have registered certificates. In my opinion, your question doesn't have enough information for other people to reproduce, or guess what's going wrong, so I think your best option is to contact nuget.org support: https://www.nuget.org/policies/Contact

Comment: @zivkan You are right, the error message is not a user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason, the value of the `authors` `.nuspec` property (`Authors` property in csproj project file) didn't match with my full name.

My full name is with diacritics.

According the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#authors), `authors` should match the profile name on nuget.org.

On nuget.org, the profile name is displayed as `<given_name><surname>` without diacritics and it didn't work.

In the account settings on nuget.org, there is the full name displayed next to my email as `<given_name> <surname>` without diacritics. This form also didn't work.

But, I'm using my Microsoft account to sign into nuget.org and in Microsoft account, the full name is `<given_name> <surname>` with diacritics. Of course, `<given_name> <surname>` with diacritics also didn't work.

So, I've tried the last possible combination - `<surname> <given_name>` **with diacritics** and then `dotnet nuget push` succeeded.